# Lowercase the letter T

Tags: python

```
string = "The", "apple", "doesn't", "fall", "far", "from", "the", "tree"
for item in string:
    print(item)

def clean_up(word):
    string = "The", "apple", "doesn't", "fall", "far", "from", "the", "tree"
    for i in string:
            i = str.lower()
    return str.lower()
```

With this code I tried to lowercase the first letter of The. First i split all the words so I get them among each other. Still the letter T is capitalized. How do I edit this code to get a small "t"

Comment: As a tip, strings are immutable, you'll have to build a new string to change any characters in them.

Comment: Your "string" is a _tuple_.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt:

```
string = "The", "apple", "doesn't", "fall", "far", "from", "the", "tree"

[s.replace('T', 't') for s in string]
```

This is one way to address the specific lowering of character 'T' as you mentioned in the problem statement.

Comment: I think you're the only one whose properly answered the question here (if he does specifically just want T to be lowercase, otherwise that's bad wording of the question), I would remove the `join` though and instead just make a new list.

Answer (score 0):

you have some problems with your code:

- each time The is capitalized beacuse you print first version of your list of strings it.
- you never call the clean_up function - to have result, you should call it and return new list with changed values
- you should call lower method directly to string value you want to change
- string in python is immutable - you should create new list of strings
- 

```
string = ["The", "apple", "doesn't", "fall", "far", "from", "the", "tree"]
for item in string:
    print(item)

def clean_up(string):
    result = []
    for i in string:
        result.append(i.lower())
    return result

print(clean_up(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not calling your function. So it's never going to be executed.
To fix this you should do it like this

```
string = "The", "apple", "doesn't", "fall", "far", "from", "the", "tree"
for item in string:
    print(clean_up(item))
```

Also you don't need another string variable in your function, nor another loop. Just pass each item in your function and return it in lowercase.

```
def clean_up(word):
    return word.lower()
```

So you complete code looks like this

```
def clean_up(word):
    return word.lower()

string = "The", "apple", "doesn't", "fall", "far", "from", "the", "tree"
for item in string:
    print(clean_up(item))
```